# Can you help me find the post?

Tags: discussion, search

I have seen a post recently about whether to use a comma before "and" in "A, B, C and D". Can someone help to find the post please? Or if it does not exists, I will post a question then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you're think of one of these:

- [Why do we use a comma before "and"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/why-do-we-use-a-comma-before-and)
- [Comma before last item in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/comma-before-last-item-in-a-list)

I found these by searching on [comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comma).